# How bind/map global hotkey when using Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, cross-platform, global-hotkey

I want to bind/map a global hotkey, which also works when application window is minimized and user not focused on it. I'm looking for a cross-platform way. Can I do this using Tkinter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With tkinter, if the window does not have keyboard focus it won't receive the keypress events so you won't be able to do what you want.

However, with pynput you can listen to the keypress events:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener

def on_press(key):
    print("PRESSED", key)


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

This should be cross-platform (but with some [patform specific limitations](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/limitations.html)).

Answer (score 3):

> I want to bind/map a global hotkey, which also works when application window minimized and not focused on it. I'm looking for a cross-platform way.

You can't do that with tkinter. Tkinter has no support for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [bindglobal](https://github.com/segalion/bindglobal)

Install with 
pip install bindglobal

Has same tkinter bind API with full combinations, but working global
Support thread safe and tkinter mainthread